# Grails unit tests not recognizing .save() on a domain class

Tags: unit-testing, testing, grails, junit

I am trying to be a good little programmer and set up Unit tests for my Grails 2.2.3 app. The unit tests that use GORM's injected `.save()` method are apparently not persisting to the mock test DB. For an example, here is what one test consists of:

```
@TestFor(TermService)
@Mock(Term)
class TermServiceTests {
    void testTermCount() {
        def t = new Term(code: "201310").save(validate: false, flush: true, failOnError: true)
        println "Printing Term: " + t.toString()

        assert 1 == Term.count() // FAILS
        assert service.isMainTerm(t) // FAILS
    }
}
```

I did a `println` that ends up printing `Printing Term: null`, meaning the Term did not save and return a Term instance. The first assertion is false with `Term.count()` returning 0.

Does anyone know why this might be? I have a mock Term and TermService (via the TestFor annotation, I believe), so I'm not quite sure why this wouldn't work. Thanks!

Edit: Here is my Term class.

```
class Term {

    Integer id
    String code
    String description
    Date startDate
    Date endDate

    static mapping = {
        // Legacy database mapping
    }

    static constraints = {
        id blank: false
        code maxSize: 6
        description maxSize: 30
        startDate()
        endDate()
    }
}
```

Comment: set the `validate:true` see if you are lacking any constraints

Comment: How does `Term` look like?

Comment: @Alidad I am lacking several constraints for sure, but I thought that setting `validate: false` would mean that validation wouldn't trigger on a save so I don't have to fill out all fields. @dmahapatro I added Term to the original post.

Comment: Why `Integer id`? GORM default is `Long id` and do not need to specify it explicitly.

Comment: Take a look at Build Test Data Plugin if you want to mock data for your unit test. I think GORM on save will validate eventually against your constraints.

Comment: It is Integer because I'm actually using a legacy database. I removed all of the mapping because I didn't figure it was relevant to this issue, but actually each field is being mapped explicitly to an existing column.

Comment: @grantmc The mocked instance will be validated before the save.

Comment: Thanks @SérgioMichels. I just added the other fields and I'm getting the same results. This is what the Term object setup looks like now:
`def t = new Term(id: 1, code: "201310", description: "Test", startDate: new Date(), endDate: new Date()).save(validate: true, flush: true, failOnError: true)`. So even with adding all of the other fields, it is apparently not persisting.

Comment: You can print the errors to see waht's going on. `println t.errors`

Comment: @SérgioMichels I added `println "Printing errors: ";  
        println t.errors` which resulted in this... `Printing errors: 
org.grails.datastore.mapping.validation.ValidationErrors: 0 errors` I'm officially stumped.

Comment: Is the `id` generator assigned? Can you try `t.id = 1` and then `t.save(...)` in the test, without setting `id` as the map construct.

Comment: @dmahapatro We have a winner! Please feel free to answer this question so I can accept that as the answer to this issue. And thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad it was helpful, added as an answer. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like `id` generator is `assigned` since you have mentioned about using legacy database. Plus `id` is not bindable by default in domain class (map construct won't work for id). So, I think you have to end up using like below:

```
def t = new Term(code: "201310")
t.id = 1
t.save(...)
```